# SQL VLOOKUP FUNCTION

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to create below results from the table that I attached as picture.All of this data located in same table.I am getting these datas from web services every day.The algorithm is;

If one of the dealer_code status changed than it may get a new code called as takıng_over_dealer code. After 1-2 days later that taking_over_dealer code will create as a dealer_code in same table. How can I match the previous dealer_code for new dealer_code ?

```
> DEALER_CODE   TAKING_OVER_DEALER_CODE
> 01047.00061   00933.00061
```

Using by below code, I can match the new created dealer_code by the way. Just I need to add , what is the previous dealer_code which was created as a taking_over dealer_code before?

```
DECLARE @TARIH AS DATE
SET @TARIH = CONVERT(varchar(10),(dateadd(dd,-1, getdate())),120)


    SELECT * INTO #TempYeni FROM        (
            SELECT A.DEALER_CODE,A.DEALER_NAME,A.DEALER_COMMERCIAL_NAME,A.FULL_ADDRESS,A.TAKING_OVER_DEALER_CODE,A.DEALER_TAX_NUMBER,A.STATUS,A.TEL,A.EMAIL,A.DEALER_MANAGER_EMAIL          FROM DEALER_DETAILED A
                WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT B.DEALER_CODE FROM DEALER_DETAILED_PRV B
                                        WHERE A.DEALER_CODE = B.DEALER_CODE
                                        AND CAST(B.[SILINMETARIHI] AS DATE) = @TARIH )          ) AS tbl
```

[image]

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: You are looking for a `JOIN`

Comment: All data located same table.. Can I join the columns for same table? How ?

Comment: @UgurYaman Yes, you can JOIN a table to itself.